# Print terms with taxonomy and metabox value

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, query, terms

I create metabox `serial_language` with ACP plugin into custom taxonomy name is `serial`.

And I want to get only terms, in which custom field value is `english, arabic`.

How to get only terms which have custom fields value `english or arabic`?

```
$wcatTerms = array(
    'get_terms' => 'serial',
    'hide_empty' => 0, 
    'parent' =>0,
    'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'get_terms' => 'serial',
            'field' => 'serial_language',
            'value' => array( 'english', 'arabic' ),
        )
));
foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) :
    echo '<a href="' .get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy ). '">' .$wcatTerm->name. '</a>';
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'relation' => 'OR',
          array(
            'key' => 'serial_language',
            'value' =>'english', 
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
          ),
          array(
            'key' => 'serial_language',
            'value' =>'arabic', 
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
          ),
    'taxonomy'  => 'serial',
    );
    $terms = get_terms( $args );
```

hope this will help